# What is better in Vue, v-if or v-show?

Tags: javascript, performance, components, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working in a project with Vue 2. I need to know in which case the performance is better: when using `v-if` or `v-show`?

I have a long list and each item's list has a form hidden that I need show and hide to click a button that has each item list.

What is better: a toggle class of `v-show` or add and remove the form with `v-if`?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show

Comment: v-if : for conditional rendering ;
v-show : for conditional display/toggle

Answer (score 86):

### tl;dr

Assuming the question is strictly about performance:

- **v-show**: expensive initial load, cheap toggling,
- **v-if**: cheap initial load, expensive toggling.

---

Evan You provided a more in depth answer at VueJS Forum

> v-show always compiles and renders everything - it simply adds the "display: none" style to the element. It has a higher initial load cost, but toggling is very cheap.
>
> Incomparison, v-if is truely conditional: it is lazy, so if its initial condition is false, it won't even do anything. This can be good for initial load time. When the condition is true, v-if will then compile and render its content. Toggling a v-if block actually tearsdown everything inside it, e.g. Components inside v-if are acually destroyed and re-created when toggled, so toggling a huge v-if block can be more expensive than v-show.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 23):

Short answer:

Use `v-if` if the condition won't change that often.

Use `v-show` if you want to toggle the condition more often.

Note: `v-show` does not remove the element from the DOM if your condition is false. So people can see it when they inspect your page.

Answer (score 8):

Adding that usage of '**v-if**' can have unexpected consequences, since it connects and disconnects elements from the DOM instead of modifying the elements' display.

For example, if you use it on a form and end up toggling that form off *using v-if*, you will receive this browser console warning:

```
    “Form submission canceled because the form is not connected”
```

If you use '**v-show**', you won't encounter this problem.

Answer (score 4):

`v-show` just only toggles **display** property of CSS(either "none" or "block"). 
When we use `v-show` the HTML DOM will be on the page only(with the "display" property).

But where as if we use `v-if` it removes the entire DOM from the page or recreates the entire DOM based on the condition.

Check this example.

```
<p v-if="ok">If Check</p>
<p v-show="ok">Show Check</p> //try to set "ok" by true and false and inspect HTML
```

Answer (score 1):

I find a blog that can explain carefully your question:
https://learnvue.co/tutorials/v-if-vs-v-show.

As my experience:

- use `v-show`: if you need to toggle something frequently.
- use `v-if`: the conditional does not change that frequently during the runtime.

**Note**: a form should use v-show if you don't want to make any breaks.

Answer (score 0):

**V-show**

It will load/render all the element in the DOM at once and if the value is false *v-show="false"* then it will set the element's display to "none"

**V-if**

It will not load/render the element until the condition is met and renders element as condition is met

Answer (score 0):

v-if:          add or remove your element.

v-show:          change visible css attibute.

if toggle often, v-show is better. otherwise, we use v-if(since css cost initial load time).

Comment: Your answer does not add anything new to the question, because info you have provided already exists in other answers.