# How to access ref element that being conditionally rendered in v-if - Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an element that being conditionally rendered with `v-if="isLogged"`, if a user is logged in:

```
<div
  v-if="isLogged"
  class="chatBlock"
  ref="chat"
></div>
```

I'm trying to get scroll height of the `chat` reference in a `mounted ()` function - `this.$refs.logged.scrollHeight`, but it's not possible, because if a user is not logged in, then this `div` won't be rendered on a mounting stage, so even if a user logs in - it won't work, because mounted stage already passed.

Is it possible to track element appearance in a DOM using `watch` method?

**UPDATE**

Added watcher, as Steven suggested below in a `mounted ()`:

```
this.$store.watch(
  (state) => {
    return this.$store.getters.isLogged
  },
  (newValue, oldValue) => {
    if (newValue) {
      this.chatHeight = this.$refs.chat.scrollHeight
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: can you add all the code and i think vue cannot be checked in dom as it is in virtual dom

Comment: after your v-if div create a `v-if-else` div and give it the same `ref="chat"`. then, in your code, just check for that ref content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a watch to `isLogged`.  When it is active, get your `chat` ref.  You will also have to check on your `mounted`, so put your logic in a common function.

So in your component:

```js
val componentOptions = {
  methods: {
    checkDiv() {
      const chatDiv = this.$refs.chat
      if (chatDiv) {
        // your code here...
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.checkDiv();
  },
  watch: {
    isLogged(value) {
      if (value) {
        this.checkDiv()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

—-

You can also use `v-show` instead of `v-if`.  That way your element will be rendered but hidden.

Comment: Updated an answer, i'm setting `scrollheight` now in a variable, so i just have to check if it's variable defined, then use it's value, right?

Comment: @AlexanderKim Put the watcher in your component, so instead of in `mounted`, you would put your logic in the `watcher`.  If your `isLogged` is in your store, use a computed property to map it, or watch '$store.state.isLogged' (with quotes) in your component.

Comment: I updated answer, removing `immediate` suggestion, because immediate is called before component mounts.  See new snippet for suggested structure.

Answer (score 18):

The accepted answer did not work for me. The watch does not guarantee that the element has already been rendered.

To make sure that the element is available, I had to use [$nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)

```js
 if (newValue) {   
     this.$nextTick(function () {
         this.chatHeight = this.$refs.chat.scrollHeight
    })
}
```

This will cause the code to be executed *after* the next DOM update cycle.

Comment: This is the right answer. After the dom is updated you will be able to use the ref.

Comment: Does this also work in Vue.JS 3 with `const chat = ref()`?

Answer (score 1):

Switching to `v-show`, as suggested by Steven, worked for me. It was actually the better option because `v-show` is cheap to toggle, unlike `v-if`, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44296275/2544357