# Vue js dynamically show/hide div

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have two divs:

```html
    <div class = "bigger">
    </div>

    <div class = "smaller">
    </div>
```

I want to hide the bigger and show the smaller div if screen width < 710 and

vice versa. I'm able to trigger resize event by:

```js
    mounted() {
        window.addEventListener("resize", this.displayWindowSize)
    })

   },

    methods () {

        displayWindowSize(event) {
           if(document.documentElement.clientWidth > 710){
              //hide smaller div
              console.log("bigger");
           }else{
               //hide bigger div
               console.log("smaller");
           }
        }
    }
```

But I couldn't find in the internet how I can hide div in vuejs.

You guys have an idea?

Edit: I want to trigger this function to hide the div whenever screenwidth changes not only once.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will be correct method.

```
methods () {

    displayWindowSize(event) {
       if(document.documentElement.clientWidth > 710){
          document.querySeletor(".smaller").style.display = "none"
          document.querySeletor(".bigger").style.display = "block"
          console.log("bigger");
       }else{
           document.querySeletor(".smaller").style.display = "block"
           document.querySeletor(".bigger").style.display = "none"
           console.log("smaller);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you want to hide it remove it, if you want to remove you can do something like

```js
methods () {
    isBigger() {
       return (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 710);
   }
}
```

and your template

```html
<div v-if="isBigger" class="bigger">
</div>

<div v-else class="smaller">
</div>
```

or

```html
<div v-show="isBigger()" class="bigger">
</div>

<div v-show="!isBigger()" class="smaller">
</div>
```

if you want to decide which one to use then check this question out
[What is better in vue.js 2, use v-if or v-show?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42419192/what-is-better-in-vue-js-2-use-v-if-or-v-show)

Answer (score 0):

thx @top talent for answering fastly. Your solution didn't work for me but I slightly changed it:

```
                if(document.documentElement.clientWidth > 710){
                document.getElementsByClassName[0].style.display = "none";
                document.getElementsByClassName("bigger")[0].style.display = "block";
            }else{
                document.getElementsByClassName("smaller")[0].style.display = "block";
                document.getElementsByClassName("bigger")[0].style.display = "none";
            }
```

workes perfect